# jQuery 1.8 unexpected behavior using a dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, each

I have a dialog in my HTML.  Some of the input elements  are generated with a unique id by appending a sequence number to them.  When the user clicks the "Book it! " button, the button function iterates over all of the inputs having the same class using each().  This way I can get the id of each input and make a GET call using ajax.   The button works properly the first time, but every time after that the inputs with a sequence number multiply.  The inputs that are not dynamically generated do not multiply.  It seems that by using each() is causing the unique elements to be created newly again.

On the first click of the "Book it! " button the URL is correctly constructed like this: `AddParty?pMemberId=0&pReservationType_0=34&pReservationType_1=63`

But, subsequent clicks increase the length like this:  `AddParty?pMemberId=0&pReservationType_0=34&pReservationType_1=63&pReservationType_0=34&pReservationType_1=63`

Here’s my dialog code in the HTML file that gets returned from a servlet.

```
<div class="reservation">
<div id="dialog-reservation-form" title="Reservation Form">
<input id="pMemberId" name="pMemberId" type="hidden" value="0"/>
<input id="pReservationType_0" class="PartyType" type="hidden" value="0"/>
<input id="pReservationType_1" class="PartyType" type="hidden" value="1"/>
</div>
<input id="plan-party" type="submit" value="Plan Party"/>
</div>
```

Here’s my javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#plan-party").button().click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-party-form").dialog("open");

    });

    $("#dialog-party-form").dialog( {
        autoOpen : false, height : 600, width : 700, modal : true, buttons :  {
            "Book it!" : function () {
                try {
                    var memberIdValue = document.getElementById("pMemberId").value;
                    var url = "AddParty?pMemberId=" + memberIdValue;
                    $(".PartyType").each(function () {
                        var reservationTypeIdName = $(this).attr('id');
                        var reservationTypeIdValue = $(this).attr('value');
                        url = url + "&" + reservationTypeIdName + "=" + reservationTypeIdValue;
                    });
                    var ajax = new AJAXInteraction(url, addHuntCallback);
                    ajax.doGet();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e.description);
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel : function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean jQuery or jQuery UI? The former isn't at version 1.8 yet.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) at all. Could you provide an example there? Alternately, try looking at what $(".PartyType") returns in a debugger and where those elements come from. `.each()` doesn't multiply elements, my guess is that somehow your whole dialog does get multiplied even if it seems like the code you posted is correct. So you'll either have to prevent that or just restrict the search to the current dialog with `$(".PartyType", this)`

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js.  I tried $(".PartyType", this) and it now it works as expected.  I'm still concerned that elements are getting copied/created, but you got me on the right track.  Thank you so much!